# Interact.js end event occurs too early

Tags: javascript

I am using **Interact.js** for some **draggable elements** on my website.
When dragging on desktop everything works as expected but when using it with a **touch device the onend event occurs too early**.

Take a look at this pen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RKoZRm

And watch the move **counter in the lower right corner**.

This is what I am basically doing:

```
interact('#draggable').draggable({
    inertia: true,
    onmove: function() {},
    onend: function() {}
});
```

However the draggable example on their website (http://interactjs.io) works as expected on touch devices and I can't really tell the difference..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is quite simple. 
You just need to add one line to your draggable element's css.

`touch-action: none`